# Streaming upload to Google Storage API when the final stream size is not known

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

So Google Storage has this great API for resumable uploads: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload which I'd like to utilize to upload a large object in multiple chunks. However this is done a in stream processing pipeline where the total amount of bytes in the stream is not know in advance.

According to the documentation of the API, you're supposed to use `Content-Range` header to tell the Google Storage API that you're done uploading the file, e.g.:

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/myBucket/o?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=xa298sd_sdlkj2 HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 1024
Content-Range: bytes 1023-2048/2048

[BYTES 1023-2048]
```

If I'm understanding how this works correctly, that `bytes 1023-2048/2048` value of the `Content-Range` header is how Google Storage determines that you're uploading the last chunk of data and it can successfully finish the resumable upload session after it's done.

In my case however the total stream size is not known in advance, so I need to *keep uploading until there's no more data to upload*. Is there a way to do this using the Google Storage API? Ideally I'd like some way of manually telling the API "hey I'm done, don't expect any more data from me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my case however the total stream size is not known in advance,

In this case you need to send `Content-Range: bytes 1023-2048/*` in the PUT requests. Note however, that these requests must be in multiples of 256KiB:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload#example_uploading_the_file

> so I need to keep uploading until there's no more data to upload. Is there a way to do this using the Google Storage API?

Yes.  You send the chunks with `bytes NNNNN-MMMMM/*`.

> Ideally I'd like some way of manually telling the API "hey I'm done, don't expect any more data from me".

You do that by either (a) sending a chunk that is not a multiple of 256KiB, or (b) sending a chunk with  `bytes NNN-MMM/(MMM+1)`.  That is, the last chunk contains the total size for the upload and indicates that it contains the last byte.

Comment: For a final "chunk", to close the upload I've used a zero-length `PUT` with `Content-Range: bytes */TOTAL_SIZE`. That seems to also "finish" the upload and create the object.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked states that:

> Content-Length. **Required** unless you are using [chunked transfer encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.1). Set to the number of bytes in the body of this initial request.

So if you click that link to chunked transfer encoding, the HTTP spec will explain how to send chunks of data until the transfer is complete:

> Chunked enables content streams of unknown size to be transferred as a
> sequence of length-delimited buffers, which enables the sender to
> retain connection persistence and the recipient to know when it has
> received the entire message.

It likely not going to be easy to implement this on your own, so I suggest finding an HTTP client library that knows how to do this for you.